# Array and looping structure

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter number of arrays: ");
    int noOfArrays = scan.nextInt();
    String students[] = new String[noOfArrays];

    System.out.println("----------------------");
    while (true){
    System.out.println("Enter Student names and scores:");

    for (int idx = 0; idx < students.length; idx++){
    int scores[] = new int[noOfArrays];
        System.out.println("\t"+ (idx+1)+ ". ");
        String studName = sc.nextLine();
        students[idx] = studName;
        for (int indx = 0; indx < scores.length; indx++){
            System.out.println("\t Score: ");
            int score = sc.nextInt();
            scores[indx] = score;            
        }            
        }
    }

}
```

I need to get this output, can somebody out there help me?

```
Enter number of arrays: 3
"----------------------
Enter Student names and scores:
    1. Name
    Score: 81
    2. Name2
    Score: 82
    3. Name3
    Score: 83
```

Comment: so, what is not working for you? also: considering your tags, is this java or c++?

Comment: what's your problem? remove `c++` tag since your code is in `java.`

Comment: I recommend first figuring out, what output you *do* get.

Comment: Sorry, I thought Java and C++ Syntax are the same.

Comment: your code is too much buggy. check my answer for your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your code have lots of bugs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("Enter number of arrays: ");
            int noOfArrays = scan.nextInt();
            String students[] = new String[noOfArrays];
            int idx=0;
            System.out.println("----------------------");

            System.out.println("Enter Student names and scores:");
            int scores[]=new int[noOfArrays];
            for ( idx = 0; idx < students.length; idx++){
                System.out.print("\t"+ (idx+1)+ ". Name ");
                sc.next(); // this is to skipping next line
                students[idx] = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.print("\tScore: ");
                    scores[idx] =sc.nextInt();        

            }

            for (int i=0;i<students.length;i++) {
                System.out.println("Name="+students[i]+"\tScore="+scores[i]  );// for printing student name and score
            }

       }
```

output:

```
Enter number of arrays: 3
----------------------
Enter Student names and scores:
    1. Name raja
    Score: 54
    2. Name gita
    Score: 99
    3. Name sita
    Score: 88
```

Comment: Thanks bro, you're a really big help. This saves me another semester in our class. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
    for (int indx = 0; indx < scores.length; indx++){
        System.out.println("\t Score: ");
        int score = sc.nextInt();
```

the `loop` iterates until `scores.length` but `scores` is undefined.